# Getting wrong value from Serial.read()

Tags: arduino-uno

I have an RGB LED, connected to my UNO R3 and would like to turn on the written color in the serial by following a table (1 for red, 2 for blue, 3 for green...) and I also want to make that if this LED is already turnt ON, I want it to turn OFF. The problem I have is that when I use Serial.read() it always returns a -1 value. Why is that? 
I leave you the code here and in case you see something wrong please tell me. Thank you very much.

```
#define RED 7
#define GREEN 4
#define BLUE 2
  String ledcolour[] = {"RED", "BLUE", "GREEN", "YELLOW", "PURPLE", "WHITE"}; //array to match the number typed to the LED colour 
  char ledstatus[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; //0 if the LED is OFF and 1 if it's ON
  String ledvaluefix[] = {"HIGH", "LOW"}; //if the ledstatus[] value is 0 it will write HIGH and if it's already ON it will write LOW
  char ledstatusfix[] = {1,0}; //to update in ledstatus[] if the LED is ON or OFF
  int led = Serial.read();
void setup() {
  pinMode(RED,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GREEN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BLUE,OUTPUT);  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Type the LED's colour you want to turn on following this table:");
  Serial.println("RED=1");
  Serial.println("BLUE=2");
  Serial.println("GREEN=3");
  Serial.println("YELLOW=4");
  Serial.println("PURPLE=5");
  Serial.println("WHITE=6");  
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()){
    Serial.println(led);
    loop();
   if (led <= 6 && led >=1){ //Checks if value is within 0-6
    if (led <=3){ //Classifies in primary or mixed colours (understand primary as just having to turn ON one single LED)
      if (ledstatus[led-1] == 0){//checks if the LED was OFF
        digitalWrite(led-1,HIGH);//turns the typed LED to HIGH
        char ledstatus[led-1] = {1};//updates the array to set the LED is now ON
        confirmer();//sends a serial confirmation message
      }else{//if it was already ON
        digitalWrite(led-1,LOW);//turns the typed LED to LOW
        char ledstatus[led-1] = {0};//updates the array to set the LED is now OFF
      }
    }else{//if it's not a primary colour
      Serial.println("YOU CHOSE " + ledcolour[led-1] + ", WHICH IS A MIXED COLOUR");
    }
    }else{//if the value is not valid (not between 0 and 6)
      Serial.println("SORRY, THE INTRODUCED VALUE IS NOT VALID");
      Serial.println("PLEASE, TRY AGAIN");
    }
  }
}
 int confirmer(){
    Serial.println("YOU CHOSE THE " + ledcolour[led-1] + " LED");//sends the serial message confirming it's been turned ON
   }
```

Comment: Why on earth are you calling loop from loop? That's nasty and leads to infinite recursion and crashing.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
 int led = Serial.read();
```

is execute before `setup()` and `loop()`, just one time. All initializations outside any function are execute before the start of the program. You have not execute `Serial.begin` yet.

You probably want to read inside the `loop` ...

**Edit:**

Second problem: you are calling `loop` recursively

```
void loop()
{
    if(Serial.available()) {
        Serial.println(led);
        loop();
```

When a byte in available in the serial port, you will call `loop`. As you never read the serial port, `Serial.available` will still return > 0, and you will enter in a never ending recursion.